# Find a point X inside triangle ABC such that (area AXB): (area BXC): (area CXA) = k : l : m where k, l, m are given constants.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I feel like areas are related to AX, BX and CX. But these are just my assumptions. I don't know how to solve this question but I stared at the rough figure of this question for a long time. I draw circles with radius AX, BX, CX from A, B, C. This doesn't help. So please try to help me. Also please provide solution more relevant to geometry than any other method.

Comment: Lookup [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point you're looking for is given by

$X = \dfrac{l}{k+l+m} A + \dfrac{m}{k+l+m} B + \dfrac{k}{k+l+m} C $

This follows from the property of [Barycentric Coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html).

For example, suppose $A = (0,0), B = (14, 0), C= (5,12) $ and you want the ratios of $[AXB]:[BXC]:[CXA] = 1:2:3$ then

$X = \dfrac{2}{6} A + \dfrac{3}{6} B + \dfrac{1}{6} C $

And this evalautes to

$X = (7, 0) + (\dfrac{5}{6}, 2) = ( \dfrac{47}{6} , 2 ) $

To verify the ratio of areas, we have the following

$[AXB] = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (B - A) \times (X - A) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (14, 0) \times (\dfrac{47}{6}, 2) \| = 14 $

$[BXC] = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (X - B) \times (C - B) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (- \dfrac{37}{6} , 2 ) \times (-9, 12) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} | - 74 + 18 | = 28 $

$[CXA] = \frac{1}{2} \| (X - A) \times (C - A) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (\dfrac{47}{6} , 2) \times (5, 12) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} | 94 - 10 | = 42 $

As a check,

$[ABC] = \dfrac{1}{2} \| (B - A) \times (C - A) \| = \dfrac{1}{2} \| B \times C \| = \dfrac{1}{2} | (14, 0) \times (5, 12) \| = 84 $

And we have $ [AXB] + [BXC] + [CXA] = 14 + 28 + 42 = 84 $

And the ratio of areas is  $14:28:42 = 1:2:3 $